# How do I load an image from a webserver to clickable Android widget

Tags: android, widget

Im trying to load an image from my webserver and display it as an `Android widget`. Im trying to have the widget update every 60 minutes as well since the image can change. The image should be `clickable` as well. I had the clickable part working perfectly with a button, but when I change it to an ImageView instead in my layout, the click portion ceases to work. And I cannot get the image to load at all. Here is my code

```
@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
Toast.makeText(context, "onUpdate", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.main);
Intent i = new Intent(context, LoadPage.class);
i.setAction(ACTION_WIDGET_LOAD);

PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, i, 0);
remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.button, pi);

appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetIds, remoteViews);

Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new MyButton(context, appWidgetManager), 1, 5000);
}

private class MyButton extends TimerTask {
RemoteViews remoteViews;
AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager;
ComponentName thisWidget;

public MyButton(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager) {
  this.appWidgetManager = appWidgetManager;
  remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.main);
  thisWidget = new ComponentName(context, ButtonWidget.class);
}

@Override
public void run() {
  Bitmap buttonimg = null;
  try {
    String name = "http://badams.ca/otwstats/get_stats.php?user=badams";
    URL url_value = new URL(name);
    buttonimg = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url_value.openConnection().getInputStream());
  } catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
  }

  i++;
  remoteViews.setBitmap(R.id.button, "setButton", buttonimg);
  appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(thisWidget, remoteViews);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix this. I was setting the image incorrectly.

Replaced:

```
remoteViews.setBitmap(R.id.button, "setButton", buttonimg);
```

with:

```
remoteViews.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.button, buttonimg);
```

and that worked flawlessly!

Answer (score 0):

You can set your image,as background of your clickable part.

Comment: If I'm stuck at not being able to download the image, how will setting the background to it solve anything?